# I want to send email for 5000 users using java . How can i achive it?

Tags: java, email, smtp, javax

My send email class is :

```
final String username = "xyz@gmail.com";
        final String password = "abcxyz";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("tikam.tailor@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("tikamchand.tailor@rayzinfotech.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

from above program i am able to send email for limited user.Problem is i want to send it for multiple user(5000 about) at a time.How can i achive it?

Comment: Make an array and put all those emailaddresses in it

Comment: It will block gmail address.